# Bootstrap 4 button pressed change color

Tags: html, css, button, bootstrap-4

I changed the bootstrap css class of the button, I changed the button color, the font size and the font color ect..

But when I press the button and hold the mouse it changes the color.

I set the color to green but when i click the button and hold the mouse it turn into blue.

This is the css code of the button

```css
.btn-outline-primary{
  width: 220px;
  background: #A4D555; /*2cc8df*/
  border: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight:450;
}

.btn-outline-primary:hover{
  background: #A4D555;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.btn-outline-primary:focus{
  background: #A4D555;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.btn-outline-primary:active{
  background: #A4D555;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: What exactly u want? A solid button or outline button?

Comment: normal solid button with the green color

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You have to add `!important` to prevent override by bootstrap definition**

```css
.btn-outline-primary{
  width: 220px;
  background: #A4D555!important; /*2cc8df*/
  border: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight:450;
}

.btn-outline-primary:hover{
  background: #A4D555!important;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none!important;
}

.btn-outline-primary:focus{
  background: #A4D555!important;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}

.btn-outline-primary:active{
  background: #A4D555!important;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Primary</button>
```

**EDIT TO YOUR COMMENT:**

> but there is still a blue border/outline when i click and press

**set:**

```
box-shadow: none!important;
```

Comment: @Taqasar Walayat tell me for more help

Comment: ok this works, but there is still a blue border/outline when i click and press

Comment: Tell me if it helps to you

Comment: Using `!important` it's not good way to edit Bootstrap styles. You should consider editing them by Sass - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/theming/

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution,

Since you said that u want solid button in comments,

I have used `btn-primary` class which is for solid buttons, instead of `btn-outline`

```css
.custom.btn-primary{
  width: 220px;
  background-color: #A4D555; /*2cc8df*/
  border: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight:450;
}

.custom.btn-primary:hover{
  background-color: #A4D555;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.custom.btn-primary:focus{
  background-color: #A4D555;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.custom.btn-primary:active{
  background-color: #A4D555!important;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
}
.custom.btn-primary:active:focus{
  background-color: #A4D555!important;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary custom">Primary</button>
```